# (C) pointers passed to func differ from original

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

Segfault I find myself unable to diagnose.

I have a benchmark func `chrono` which receives an array `strings` of pointers to randomly generated strings, and an array of corresponding `sizes`. For debug, I print `strings` (the pointer to pointers), `strings[1]` (one of them), and `sizes` (the pointer). (I also print some strings in `chrono`, to be sure, and compare to their original contents in the func that generates them: all is fine up to there.) What is to be benchmarked is a func that feeds a pack of strings into a string pool:

```
void pool_store_pack (StringPool * pool,
     char ** strings, size_t * sizes, uint n_new);
```

For debug, I print the same data inside pool_store_pack. And the values are different. `strings` has changed, and both `strings[1]` and `sizes` are null. Here is an example output:

```
strings:0x9842fa8 (n°1:0x984200c)
sizes:0x9843f48
some strings: `@PR` `MOB` `TBQ`

strings:0x804a824 (n°1:(nil))
sizes:(nil)
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried to reduce the bug to a simpler form, but it is difficult precisely because it is test code, not app code, that drives an autonomous piece of library. When I try to reproduce the bug from scratch, I just get as expected pointers and pointers to pointers with the same values in the receiving funcs as in the sending one. However, I can post the code of the 3 relevant funcs if it helps (but you won`t be able to run it, since it just drives other funcs).

I am pretty sure to be missing an obvious point, but cannot see it and am blocked and frustrated for hours ;-) Can you help?

EDIT: So, here is the whole code involved:

```
/*  Put pack of strings in pool.
*/
void pool_store_pack (StringPool * pool,
         char ** strings, size_t * sizes, uint n_new) {
   pool_grow(pool, n_new);

   // debug /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   printfl("n_new:%u", n_new);
   printfl("strings:%p (n°1:%p)", strings, strings[1]);
   printfl("sizes:%p", sizes);
   printfl("some sizes: %u %u %u", sizes[1], sizes[3], sizes[9]);
   printfl("some strings: '%s' '%s' '%s'", strings[1], strings[3], strings[9]);
   end();

   uint i;
   for (i = 0; i < n_new; i++) pool_store(pool, strings[i], sizes[i]);
}

// generate random strings (constants used here are defined somewhere else)
static char ** data_strings (char ** p_bytes) {
   char * bytes = malloc(n_strings * l * sizeof(char));
   check_mem(bytes);
   char ** strings = malloc(n_strings * sizeof(char *));
   check_mem(strings);
   char * s;
   uint i,j;
   srandom(time(NULL));

   for (i=0; i<n_strings; i++) {
      s = bytes + i*l;
      s[size] = NUL;
      for (j=0; j<size; j++) s[j] = '@' + random()%n_letters;
      strings[i] = s;
   }

   //~ for (i=0; i<n_strings; i++) printf("'%s' ", strings[i]); line();
   printfl("some strings: '%s' '%s' '%s'", strings[1], strings[3], strings[9]);
   * p_bytes = bytes;
   return strings;
}

// benchmark
static void chrono () {
   printfl ("=== chrono pool ===============================================");
   uint i;
   clock_t t1, t2;
   float dt;

   // test data string
   char * bytes;
   char ** strings = data_strings(& bytes);
   // string sizes are all equal to size (3)
   size_t * sizes = malloc(n_strings * sizeof(size_t));
   check_mem(sizes);
   for (i=0; i<n_strings; i++) sizes[i] = size;

   // debug ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   printfl("n_strings:%u", n_strings);
   printfl("strings:%p (n°1:%p)", strings, strings[1]);
   printfl("sizes:%p", sizes);
   printfl("some sizes: %u %u %u", sizes[1], sizes[3], sizes[9]);
   printfl("some strings: '%s' '%s' '%s'", strings[1], strings[3], strings[9]);

   // now, feed the pool
   StringPool * pool = stringpool();
   t1 = clock();
   pool_store_pack(pool, strings, sizes, n_strings);
   t2 = clock();
   end();
   dt = 1.0 * (t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   print("pool data   : "); show_pool_data(pool);
   print("pool stats  : "); show_pool_stats(pool, false);
   printfl("time  : %.3f", dt);

   free(bytes);
   free(strings);
}
```

Comment: Lesson learned: don't return automatic arrays.

Comment: given `sizes:(nil)`, it appears you are trying to dereference sizes to get the first array element, and fail. (that is in line 15, just after the malloc() )

Comment: What compiler warnings do you have enabled?

Comment: There you go : ` printfl("some sizes: %u %u %u", sizes[1], sizes[3], sizes[9]);` dereferencing size if it is NULL.

Comment: What is `n_strings` value?

Comment: @joseph-quinsey: `CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -g -O0`

Comment: @weston: `n_strings=999; size=3; n_letters=27; l=4;` (`l` is just `size` + 1 for NUL).

Comment: I'm sure it's a really, really stupid bug, one of the series that will make me ashamed when I know the reason ;-) Denis

Comment: What line do you think if fails on?

Comment: And this is definitely `c`, not `c++`? Just presence of `uint`, `clock_t`, `true`, `false`, you might have those defined, but as they are normal `c++` it looks like this is miss-tagged.

Comment: Is there a declaration of pool_store_pack() which does not match the definition? Or do stringpool() or pool_grow() misbehave by overflowing some buffer? Test the latter by moving your debug code to immediately before the invocation and immediately at the start of the function. And do turn on compiler warnings and use valgrind to test for memory corruption.

Comment: @denis63 - I assume since you mention "segfault" you're on Linux, right?  What compiler? GCC?  Are you using a debugger?  GDB?  If so, add `-ggdb` to the CFLAGS and run your program under GDB.  If you need command line args to your program, run `gdb --args <programName> <arg1> <arg2>...`.  When it segfaults it should point you to the exact line of code that's segfaulting.  Which one is it?

Comment: @weston: This is true, plain C; didn't even know C++ has something like uint (it's a typedef). (In fact aside uint they are all defined in C headers.) Denis

Comment: @weston: It fails on debug prints, in `pool_store_pack` when dereferencing some null pointer... exactly when trying to write "some sizes". (But the same happens if I try to write a string, indeed.)

Comment: @denis63 - How do you know it segfaults there?  Because that's the last thing printed, or because your debugger tells you it was on that line when it segfaulted?  If you're trusting the printed output, don't.  You may have additional printed text that's still in buffers which your program already sent but which isn't yet displayed.  You need to be using a debugger... are you?

Comment: OK runs! There were 2 bugs infact, interacting. First, a wrong redefinition of a static constant giving an initial set of strings to feed the pool (in fact only ""). Second, an inversion of 2 instructions making the pool beeing used before initialised. The interaction is that the init also used `pool_store_pack` (to feed the pool with initial strings). ==> What I got as debug info was the data from calling this func `pool_store_pack` for pool init (thus, strings[1] was nil because there is only one, ""!!!). And sizes was nil because it is the static constant wrongly changed... Mama mia!

Comment: Thanks to you all! Unfortunately I cannot vote you up, since there are only comments...

Answer (score 2):

OK runs! There were 2 bugs in fact, interacting with each other. First, a wrong redefinition of a static constant giving the sizes of an initial set of strings to feed the pool (in fact only `""`, so this set has length 1). Second, an inversion of 2 instructions making the pool beeing used before initialised. The interaction is that the initialisation also used pool_store_pack to feed the pool with said initial strings.

==>

What I got as debug output (and showed you) was reflecting the data from calling this func pool_store_pack for pool *initialisation*, not from the chrono func (thus, `strings[1]` was nil because there is only one string in the initial set!). And `sizes` was nil because it is the static constant wrongly changed... Mama mia!

Thanks to you all! Unfortunately I cannot vote you up, since there are only comments...

Comment: You can still accept your own answer, it's perfectly proper conduct at SO, to mark the issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks, hyde, had not even noticed the check sign. I would do it but SO's software does not let me right now (tells me I must wait until tomorrow).